Function to clear any value by assigning to it a default constructed value of same type
I want to create a function clear such that, when calling it like this clear(v), replaces v with a default constructed value of the same type (which is a zero initialization for built-in types). The simplest solution v = {} doesn't work for arrays because you can't assign to it, and so I end up doing this:
    template<class T>
    void clear(T& v) noexcept
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_array_v<T>) {
            using base_t = std::remove_all_extents_t<T>;

            if constexpr (std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<base_t>)
                std::memset(v, 0, sizeof(v));
            else {
                // To deal with multidimensional arrays, I make sure to get pointers
                // the first and last actual value of the array.
                base_t* it = reinterpret_cast<base_t*>(v);
                base_t* end = it + sizeof(v) / sizeof(base_t);

                for (; it != end; ++it)
                    clear(*it);
            }
        } else
            v = {};
    }

I would like to know about potential pitfalls about that implementation, specifically regarding aliasing and alignment rules. I think the implementation is OK but I'm not sure. The check for trivially constructor base type is because I have to make sure that the default constructor of the type doesn't add custom initialization values for its member in the initialization list or by means of a default initializer. In other words, that for that type zero-initializing it and default-value-initializing it are synonymous.
But the implementation feels too much complicated than it should, and also I prefer the compiler to take care of all of this. I just want to fix the problem of arrays not being assignables, and so I ended up doing this:
    template<class T>
    void clear(T& v) noexcept
    {
        struct helper { T v; };
        *reinterpret_cast<helper*>(&v) = {};
    }

and I want to know about potential pitfalls of that approach too.

template<class T> void clear(T &t) noexcept { t = {}; }template<class T, std::size_t N> void clear(T (&a)[N]) noexcept { for (auto& e : a) {clear(e); } } should do what you want, and is not complicated, your version is more complicated as you want manual optimization with memset.

Your multi-dimentional code is pedantically UB, you cannot treat T[N][M] as T[N * M].

@Jarod42 This should be the answer (posted as an answer, not a comment ;) )

Default-initialization of basic types is not the same is zero initialization, see here.

@Fareanor: I read the question as listing pitfall of provided implementations, not alternative.

@Jarod42 Oh you're right, it seems that I overlooked the question.

@Jarod42 Regarding my multi-dimensional treatment, consider that whenever I dereference the iterator, I'm accesing an object of type base_t throw a pointer of type base_t. I'm not "accessing" an array of T[N][M] through a pointer of type T[N * M] or something like that, which I know violates strict aliasing rules. I'm only playing with T[N][M] as T[N * M] to do pointer arithmetics, but at the time of accesing an object, the pointer I'm desrefencing matches the type of the object being accessed (an object of type base_t).

@ABu doesn't matter. That pointer arithmetic is strictly UB

It's also fairly sus that you want this function at all. If you want a default constructed variable, just declare a new one. If you have an array that just barely fits on the stack, but want a second one, move both of them into std::vectors

@Caleth I have also a multi_clean function that takes a variadic template that calls clear for every received parameter. The context is adapting a legacy function of around 2k lines with ~150 variables declared at the beginning of the function, with tons of individual calls to memset and = 0 assignations inside a lot of places whenever the code needs to use some subset of variables again, and doing a proper refactorization of the function from scratch is out of reach. The multi_clean function allows me to turn blocks of re-initializations in a single sentence.

@ABu I don't think that's a helpful thing to do. Either fix the function, or leave the existing resetting

The first implementation is pedantically UB for multidimensional arrays, a T[M][N] is not accessible like a T[M * N].
The second implementation has undefined behaviour. There isn't a helper at that address, so you have violated strict aliasing.
A defined way of doing what you want (post C++20) is
template<class T>
T& clear(T& v) noexcept
{
    std::destroy_at(&v);
    return *std::construct_at(&v);
}

This still has caveats. The type must be nothrow default constructable, nothrow destructible to not fall afoul of the noexcept, and the object must not be potentially overlapping (e.g. a base subobject). Pointers and references to the previous object are now invalid, you can only access it via the returned reference.
Prior to that you can backport those. N.b. C++17 has std::destroy_at, but it is undefined for arrays.
template<class T>
constexpr void destroy_at(T* p) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<T>)
        for (auto &elem : *p)
            (destroy_at)(std::addressof(elem));
    else
        p->~T(); 
}

template< class T, class... Args >
constexpr T* construct_at(T* p, Args&&... args) {
    return ::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

Alternatively you can just copy the structure of the destroy_at backport
template<class T>
constexpr void clear(T& v) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_array_v<T>)
        for (auto &elem : v)
            clear(elem);
    else
        v = {}; 
}

This is not strictly the same as the destroy_at / construct_at version, as it requires operator=, which might not exist for a type, or it might do something different than the default constructor.

Both versions have undefined behavior if v is a base class subobject or otherwise potentially-overlapping. Before C++20, classes containing references or const members are also not transparently-replaceable and there are still some other edge cases (e.g. a mutable member object of a const complete object). (Not purely theoretical UB btw. This can cause reused tail padding to be incorrectly overwritten in practice.)

@user17732522 I've added caveats. Iirc you can always re-use storage, but the original reference now dangles.

@Caleth Ok. I could remove the multi-dimensional treatment and just iterate cleanly. In our code base, multidimensional arrays are rare, but it feels naive to iterate, let's say, to an array of chars to zero-initialize each char one by one. I guess the compiler is smart enough to optimize that out anyway, but I prefer to be a bit explicit about it.

@ABu read up on the as-if rule. The compiler can look at this function, see that you are zero initialising a trivial type, and issue the equivalent of memset. You don't have to write the memset yourself in that case. Trying to be explicit about those sorts of things leads you into UB land, where the compiler "optimises" by e.g. doing nothing

Ok you convinced me.

Pointers and references to the previous object are now invalid, you can only access it via the returned reference. In c++20 references and pointers to an  object transparently replaced remain valid.
